# What does the Latin abbreviation "Form." stand for?

Tags: new-latin, abbreviations

I came across a medal commemorating the coronation of Charles XV in 1860. The inscriptions on the medal are all in Latin. I am aware of a few latin abbreviations centered around the creators of medals like these:
FEC. = [fecit](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/fecit)
SC. = [sculpsit](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sculpsit)
DIR. = [direxit](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/direxit)

One of the inscriptions on the medal is sculpsit:

> J. E. ERICSSON **SC**.

But there is another abbreviation on this medal that I am not familiar with:

> C. G. OVARNSTRӦM **FORM**.

What Latin verb is this supposed to be?

My guess would be "format" but how is that different than "sculpsit"? I have included a picture that I took of the medal for reference:

[image]

Comment: My guess is *formavit*, but I don't know the process of making such a medal well enough to guess what it means. Judging by the word alone, it could be "shaped", "formed", "prepared", or something similar.

Comment: Traditionally the die was 'sculpted' with chisels and punches. It probably means that this artist shaped the design in wax or clay and the die was cast from that. *Sculpsit* and *scripsit* are in the perfect tense: So Joonas is certainly right that **FORM** stands for the perfect *formavit,*

Comment: So Ericsson 'sculpted' the die from a shaped clay or wax design that Ovarnstrom 'formed'?

Comment: If the artist forms a wax or clay original, a craftsman could sculpt the die to match. Or, if the clay original is full-size, the die itself can be cast, or (on clay or wax) built up with layers of electroplating, using the artist's original work directly. The die is then used to strike the medal/coin.

Comment: @Hugh Can you turn your comments into an answer? There hasn't been a single answer so far, and what you have would already make a nice one.

Comment: Or, _formavit_ could mean _coined_ (just guessing.) The original was sculpted, a mould was made from it, and someone else minted the medals using the mould?

Comment: [This dictionary](https://books.google.cl/books?id=2l5gAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PT733&ots=Djudcm2uY0&dq=formare%20latin%20coin&pg=PT733#v=onepage&q=formare%20latin%20coin&f=false) says _formare_ can mean _to mould_. If my English doesn't treason me, it could be closer to coin/mint or even cast a mould than _sculpsit_ @JoonasIlmavirta

Comment: @Rafael If *formare* can mean "to mould", that would make the meaning very explicit. A mere "to form" is quite vague here. Would you like to add that as an answer? That dictionary entry is very useful for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it seems that *formavit* here means that someone *moulded* (minted, coined) the medal based on what someone else sculpted (*sculpsit*) first.

[This dictionary](https://books.google.cl/books?id=2l5gAAAAcAAJ&lpg=PT733&ots=Djudcm2uY0&dq=formare%20latin%20coin&pg=PT733#v=onepage&q=formare%20latin%20coin&f=false) supports the idea of *formare* meaning *to mould*.

Note that the dictionary was edited in the XVIII Century, while L&S doesn't even list the verb *formare* (I think *formam dare* is more classical.)

From what I can understand from [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacagawea_dollar) (and what I remember,) coins and medals are designed by sculptors, leaving the serial production to mints, so I would say that **Ericsson was the designer** and **Ovarnström was in charge of the minting process**.

Answer (score 2):

From Hugh's comments:

Traditionally the die was 'sculpted' with chisels and punches. It probably means that this artist shaped (*formed*) the design in wax or clay and the die was cast from that. Sculpsit and scripsit are in the perfect tense: So Joonas is certainly right that FORM stands for the perfect **formavit**,

If the artist *forms* a wax or clay original, a craftsman could sculpt the die to match. Or, if the clay original is full-size, the die itself can be cast, or (on clay or wax) built up with layers of electroplating, using the artist's original work directly. The die is then used to strike the medal/coin.

Comment: See Rafael's comments to the question above. If *formare* can mean "to mould", it's role in the process becomes clearer.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta♦: Quite possibly! Perhaps that could be added as a separate answer?